# Rails: finding assets which have been compiled in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-sprockets

I am working on a legacy app, and I just found out that `config.assets.compile` was set to `true` in `production.rb`

Now, while we'll test the hell out of it on staging, I want to find all the assets which *should* be part of the `precompile` array if I can.

What I did was to go into the `tmp/cache` directory and have a look around:

```
rails@foobar-production-app:/srv/www/app/shared/tmp/cache$ find . -type f | grep foobar
./57A/651/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foobar.com%2Fassets%2Fmathquill.css%3F
./AEE/971/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foobar.com%2Fassets%2Fmathquill%2Fmathquill.min.js%3F
./222/C12/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foobar.com%2Fassets%2Flegacy-b56a7fd21baf98f1ac20cd77ca77a184.js%3F
./C96/561/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foobar.com%2Fassets%2Fmathquill%2Fmathquill.min.js%3Fv2.6%3D
```

And I found the file I was expecting to `legacy.js` which I knew was missing from precompile. Is it likely that I just need to add the files matching my domain name to the assets precompile and then it should all be OK to push to production with `config.assets.compile = false` or are there other places / files I should look for to fix up.

I did find a heap of `assets` files - like this:

`./assets/D1D/0F0/sprockets%2F663a54e3907dfc958d784233a6dd0e9a`

and the contents of which do contain links to images etc, but I can see those fingerprinted assets in `public/assets` (yes, we are actually precompiling the assets in production).  Or is the presence of *any* of these sprockets file pointing to something that is an issue and should be fixed?

I guess my question is, how can I most easily find any missing assets, other than just setting the flag, pushing to staging, and clicking around.